# Picture won't open in File Dialog, Tkinter, Pillow

Tags: python, tkinter, python-imaging-library, filedialog

I have written this.

Its short and supposed to open a file dialog window, with buttons "open a file, turn, save, exit."
I want to open a jpeg, turn it 180° and then save it and quit.

The program starts, but doesnt open the picture in the file dialog window after I select it in the browser.

```
from tkinter import *
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import filedialog
from tkinter.filedialog import askopenfilenames


root = Tk() ##pro Tkinter

root.title('Image Browser')
root.geometry('100x100')


def open():
    global my_image
    root.filename = filedialog.askopenfilenames(initialdir='/gui/pillow', filetypes=[('Images','*.jpg *.jpeg *.png')])
    #my_label = Label(root, text = root.filename).pack()
    my_image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open(root.filename))
    my_image_label = Label(image=my_image).pack()

def turn():
    return
    my_image = my_image.transpose(Image.FLIP_RIGHT_LEFT)

def save():
    return
    my_image.save('somepic.jpg')


button = Button (root, text = 'Select a File', command = open)
button.pack()
button4 = Button (root, text = 'Turn', command = turn)
button4.pack()
button2 = Button (root, text = 'Save', command = save)
button2.pack()
button3 = Button(root, text = 'Exit', command = jadro.quit)
button3.pack()


root.mainloop()
```

After I select and try to open the file, it says this

```
AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'seek'
```

I feel like I've tried everything, but cant seem to solve it.
Thanks for any help

Comment: Please show the full exception trace. That will show exactly where this error is occurring

Comment: Its here:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\RJ\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1921, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "c:\Users\RJ\Desktop\pillow\main_buttons.py", line 20, in open
    my_image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open(root.filename))
  File "c:\Users\RJ\Desktop\pillow\venv\lib\site-packages\PIL\Image.py", line 2981, in open
    fp = io.BytesIO(fp.read())
AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'read'

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Regarding the error message: 1. That doesn't match what you wrote in the title. 2. You should include it *in the post itself*, *formatted as code*. Use the `Edit` link under your post to add the information.

Comment: Also: please read https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/ and try to diagnose and trace the problem yourself before posting. For example: when `root.filename = filedialog.askopenfilenames(initialdir='/gui/pillow', filetypes=[('Images','*.jpg *.jpeg *.png')])` happens, what do you expect the value of `root.filename` to look like? *Does* it? *Did you check*? If it doesn't meet your expectation, the next step is to *read the documentation* for `filedialog.askopenfilenames`.

Comment: Of course I've tried for several hours, otherwise I wouldnt be here?
The thing is that I dont see the problem, thats why I came here to seek help.

Answer (score 1):

`askopenfilenames` return a tuple.

Try this instead

```
my_image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open(root.filename[0]))
```

Answer (score 1):

From [Python DOC](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dialog.html)

```
tkinter.filedialog.askopenfilename(**options)
tkinter.filedialog.askopenfilenames(**options)
```

*The above two functions create an Open dialog and return the selected filename(s) that correspond to existing file(s).*

Therefore `askopenfilenames()` returns a tuple of filenames, instead `Image.open(fp)` requires a file pointer as argument, not a tuple.

From [Pillow DOC](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/Image.html):

```
PIL.Image.open(fp, mode='r', formats=None)
```

*fp – A filename (string), pathlib.Path object or a file object. The file object must implement file.read, file.seek, and file.tell methods, and be opened in binary mode.*